# How to render a form for a new Account object on every page that has a dashboard element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that I want to render on every page that has a dashboard partial:

accounts/new.slim

```
#addAccount-modal.modal.hide.fade style="display: none;"
  h5 Create a New Account
  = form_for @account do |f|
    p Name: 
    = f.text_field :name, value: "New Account"

    = f.submit "Create Account", class: "btn"
```

_dashboard.slim

```
.col-md-2
  ul.nav.nav-stacked#dashboard-nav
    li
      a href="#" Report
      a href="#" Accounts

      a data-toggle="modal" href="#addAccount-modal" + Add
=render "accounts/new"
```

The issue is that I don't have `@account` instantiated on every page. I currently only have it in my `Accounts#new` method so it is breaking on every other page except for this since @account for the form is nil.

Is there a simple way to make sure `@account` is instantiated on every page, or do I have to manually just add it to every page that will require it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `Account.new` in the `form`:

```
form_for Account.new do |f|
```